# Why is div hover constrained to mat-grid-tile?

Tags: html, css, angular, sass

I have a div that shows content when the user hovers over the mat-grid-tile.

I want it to be big enough to show all of its contents, however this is not happening because it seems to be constrained inside the mat-grid-tile.

What it looks like before hover:
[image]

What it looks like when hovering:
[image]

What I want it to look like:
[image]

**HTML**:

```
<mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let quickPhrase of phrases.QuickPhraseList ; let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i"
                                   [ngClass]="{'selected':phraseSelected === quickPhrase.Phrase}"  >
                        <div class="phrase-box">
                            <p>{{quickPhrase.PhraseTitle != null ? quickPhrase.PhraseTitle.substring(0,25) : "Add Title"}}</p>
                            <span>
                                <p class="hover-phrase-title"><strong>Title:</strong><br>{{quickPhrase.PhraseTitle}}</p>
                                <p class="hover-phrase-content"><strong>Quick Phrase:</strong><br>{{quickPhrase.Phrase}}</p>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <mat-icon *ngIf="false" mat-list-icon dndHandle>
                            drag_handle
                        </mat-icon>
                    </mat-grid-tile>
```

**CSS**:

```
  .phrase-box {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    
  }
  
  span { display: none; }
  
  .phrase-box:hover > span {
    width: 84%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: -100px;
    left: 15%;
    border: 2px solid rgb(187, 186, 186);
    background-color: #fff;
    padding-left: 10px;
    z-index: 999;
  }

  .hover-phrase-title {
      margin-top: 10px;
  }
  .hover-phrase-content {
      margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
```

Comment: When a user hovers over the grid tile, what do you want to happen so that all the content is shown? Do you want the grid to grow, or perhaps overflow? I’m not sure what end result you’re trying to achieve.

Comment: hi @SamSabin , I just added some screenshots to display what is happening, and what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: What does it look like before you hover over it?

Comment: @SamSabin I just added another image that shows what it looks like before the hover.

Comment: So you want it to expand and push the column to the left over? Or do you just want it to cover everything like a pop-up?

Comment: @SamSabin More of cover everything like a popup. It should not push any columns over.

Comment: Does that make sense @SamSabin ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out what was causing this. There was an inherited CSS style. Overflow had the value hidden inherited. I changed css for .mat-grid-tile to be:

```
overflow:visible;
```

And now it works properly.